# saving search results as text instead of list

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.8 and currently am working on a Blog application. When i search for tweets( just a name instead of posts) , i want to save the search results obtained after querying the database, as text instead of list. My view function is as below:

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q','')
    if query:
        qset = (
            Q(text__icontains=query)

            #Q(hashes__icontains=query)
            #Q(artist__icontains=query)
        )
        results = Tweet.objects.filter(qset).distinct()

    else:
        results = []
    number_of_results = len(results)

    search_item = query
    returned_items = []
    for res in results:
        text = res.text
        returned_items.append(text)

    returns = returned_items[:]

    search = Search(search_item=search_item,returns=returns)
    search.save()

    context =    {'query':query,'results':results,'number_of_results':number_of_results,'title':'Search results for '+request.GET.get('q','')}
    return render_to_response("tweets/search.html",context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

also, the snapshot of my search table in the database is as shown below:[image: Search table]

Please help me out friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should join the returned list using the comma separted values. This will return the string.

```
returns = ', '.join(returned_items)
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is setting returns to a list:

```
returns = returned_items[:]
```

If you want to access the first string, set it to returned_items[0]. If you want to join all strings in the list, use join()

```
returns = "".join(returned_items)
```